# Append procedure in scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I have been recently learning Scheme and in a tutorial i found a procedure called append

```
(define append
(lambda (ls1 ls2)
(if (null? ls1)
    ls2
    (cons (car ls1) (append (cdr ls1) ls2)))))
```

I didn't understand the logic behind this but understood that it attaches the members of the first list one by one to the second list.Can anyone explain me the last line of the procedure?
And what does cons with the two arguments mean?

I ran

```
(trace (append '( a b c) '(d e f)))
```

and ended up with

```
[Entering #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: (a b c)
      (d e f)]
[Entering #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: (b c)
      (d e f)]
[Entering #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: (c)
      (d e f)]
[Entering #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: ()
      (d e f)]
[(d e f)
  <== #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: ()
      (d e f)]
[(c d e f)
  <== #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: (c)
      (d e f)]
[(b c d e f)
  <== #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: (b c)
      (d e f)]
[(a b c d e f)
  <== #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: (a b c)
      (d e f)]
;The object (a b c d e f), passed as an argument to procedure-lambda, is not a procedure.
```

It'd be gud if you explain how to read this trace results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you use trace wrong. You need to call it on the procedure you are going to trace, not an expression. Like this:

```
(trace append)
```

The last line is trace complaining about it not being able to trance the list `(a b c d e f)`. The trace output you see is from a previous call to `trace` done right!

Now for how to read.. Every entry looks like:

```
[Entering #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: (a b c)
      (d e f)]
```

That means the same as `(append '(a b c) '(d e f))`. Here is the exit trace from the same instance:

```
[(a b c d e f)
  <== #[compound-procedure 4 append]
Args: (a b c)
      (d e f)]
```

This says it returns `(a b c d e f)` and the call was `(append '(a b c) '(d e f))`.

Notice that these two doesn't come after each other. The reason is that the `cons` step needs to wait for the recursive step to do `(b c d e f)` first. All lists are made from end to beginning.

If we call `(append '(a b c) '(d e f))` this is what happens:

```
(append '(a b c) '(d e f))                          ; ==>
(cons 'a (append '(b c) '(d e f)))                  ; ==>
(cons 'a (cons 'b (append '(c) '(d e f))))          ; ==>
(cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c (append '() '(d e f))))) ; <==
(cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c '(d e f))))              ; <==
(cons 'a (cons 'b '(c d e f)))                      ; <==
(cons 'a '(b c d e f))                              ; <==
'(a b c d e f)                                      ; result
```

In reality the parameters expressions evaluates to values, but I quote them here so that you can paste these in the REPL and get the same result on all lines.

the evaluation order here is the same as in your trace.

Comment: Tnq! But when i run (trace append) i get ;Unspcified return value

Comment: @Vishal Yes. You are after the side effect, not the returned value. After you have done `(trace append)` it will trace every invocation until you turn it off with `(untrace append)` or redefine `append`.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
(cons (car ls1) (append (cdr ls1) ls2))
```

simply adds the current element on the first list to the result of appending the rest of the first list to the second list. To understand why this works in the end, see how the recursion ends when all the elements in the first list have been consed, we stick the second list in the end:

```
(if (null? ls1) ls2
```

And that's how it works! it's a recursive process, as you can see.

Comment: Tnq :)!What does cons mean with the car and the append beside it?
I mean how does that statement work

Comment: That's very basic stuff :( let's start with reading the docs, shall we?. Cons simply sticks two things together, the first element of the first list `(car ls1)` and the result of the recursion `(append (cdr ls1) ls2)`. We use cons to build lists, for example: (cons 1 (cons 2 '()))

Comment: I got it! Can you suggest a gud tutorial for learning scheme?